# Service Worker (Workbox) isn't delegating routes to our SPA on reload

Tags: reactjs, react-router, single-page-application, progressive-web-apps, workbox

We're building a SPA for an internal application at work, specifically we're building a PWA that is supposed to be offline-first.

At the moment, we're doing just fine when someone reloads the page from the `/` route. But any other route causes the app to dinosaur, and I have no idea why.

In our service worker we just have

```js
importScripts("/precache-manifest.cce3b8ef68b2862904ee55d44aac3447.js", "https://storage.googleapis.com/workbox-cdn/releases/3.6.3/workbox-sw.js");

workbox.precaching.precacheAndRoute(self.__precacheManifest || []);
```

And then a sync script for pushing local work to the backend.

In the SPA itself, we're using `react` and `react-router`. In the root of the application we have the following routes:

```js
<Switch>
  <Route path="/_utils" component={DexUtils} />
  <Route path="/callback" component={Callback} />
  <Route exact path="/login" component={loginHandler} />
  <Route path="/" component={App} />
</Switch>
```

So, what happens is the last route should capture anything that isn't 1 of the other 3 routes.

The service worker, if I'm not mistaken should work without issue, but like I said, every time we reload the page from a route that isn't `/`, we lose connection and the app becomes unusable until you navigate back to `/`.

Edit:
Here's the service worker register script:

```js
/* eslint-disable */
// In production, we register a service worker to serve assets from local cache.

// This lets the app load faster on subsequent visits in production, and gives
// it offline capabilities. However, it also means that developers (and users)
// will only see deployed updates on the "N+1" visit to a page, since previously
// cached resources are updated in the background.

// To learn more about the benefits of this model, read...
// This link also includes instructions on opting out of this behavior.

const isLocalhost = Boolean(
  window.location.hostname === 'localhost' ||
    // [::1] is the IPv6 localhost address.
    window.location.hostname === '[::1]' ||
    // 127.0.0.1/8 is considered localhost for IPv4.
    window.location.hostname.match(
      /^127(?:\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)){3}$/
    )
);

export default function register() {
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' && 'serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    // The URL constructor is available in all browsers that support SW.
    const publicUrl = new URL(process.env.PUBLIC_URL, window.location);
    if (publicUrl.origin !== window.location.origin) {
      // Our service worker won't work if PUBLIC_URL is on a different origin
      // from what our page is served on. This might happen if a CDN is used to
      // serve assets; see https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/2374
      return;
    }

    window.addEventListener('load', () => {
      const swUrl = `${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/service-worker.js`;

      if (isLocalhost) {
        // This is running on localhost. Lets check if a service worker still exists or not.
        checkValidServiceWorker(swUrl);

        // Add some additional logging to localhost, pointing developers to the
        // service worker/PWA documentation.
        navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(() => {
          console.log(
            'This web app is being served cache-first by a service ' +
              'worker. To learn more, visit ...'
          );
        });
      } else {
        // Is not local host. Just register service worker
        registerValidSW(swUrl);
      }
    });
  }
}

function registerValidSW(swUrl) {
  navigator.serviceWorker
    .register(swUrl)
    .then(registration => {
      registration.onupdatefound = () => {
        const installingWorker = registration.installing;
        installingWorker.onstatechange = () => {
          if (installingWorker.state === 'installed') {
            if (navigator.serviceWorker.controller) {
              // At this point, the old content will have been purged and
              // the fresh content will have been added to the cache.
              // It's the perfect time to display a "New content is
              // available; please refresh." message in your web app.
              console.log('New content is available; please refresh.');
            } else {
              // At this point, everything has been precached.
              // It's the perfect time to display a
              // "Content is cached for offline use." message.
              console.log('Content is cached for offline use.');
            }
          }
        };
      };
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error('Error during service worker registration:', error);
    });
}

function checkValidServiceWorker(swUrl) {
  // Check if the service worker can be found. If it can't reload the page.
  fetch(swUrl)
    .then(response => {
      // Ensure service worker exists, and that we really are getting a JS file.
      if (
        response.status === 404 ||
        response.headers.get('content-type').indexOf('javascript') === -1
      ) {
        // No service worker found. Probably a different app. Reload the page.
        navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(registration => {
          registration.unregister().then(() => {
            window.location.reload();
          });
        });
      } else {
        // Service worker found. Proceed as normal.
        registerValidSW(swUrl);
      }
    })
    .catch(() => {
      console.log(
        'No internet connection found. App is running in offline mode.'
      );
    });
}

export function unregister() {
  if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(registration => {
      registration.unregister();
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: How are you registering the service worker?

Comment: @GauntFace we are using the standard service worker registration that comes out of create-react-app v1.1.5. I can post the full registration if necessary.

Comment: yes please, I don't know what the standard is and it might be helpful.

Comment: Posted the registration script

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that your service worker is at the root of your domain `/service-worker.js`, you may just need to add a navigation route.

https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-routing#how_to_register_a_navigation_route

Answer (score 5):

Those using [`generateSW`](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/reference-docs/latest/module-workbox-build#.generateSW) can use the `navigateFallback` option like so:

> #### workbox-config.js
>
> ```
> module.exports = {
>   "navigateFallback": "index.html",
>   "globDirectory": "build-client/",
>   "globPatterns": [
>     "**/*.{js,json,png,html,txt}"
>   ],
>   "swDest": "build-client/sw.js"
> };
> ```

Comment: This was crucial ty. 

I kept trying to set the path, and folder, etc. 

Webpack is automatically creating the html file for me and placing it in the (build output) dist folder. 

This service worker runs FROM the (build output) dist folder, so all the extra paths etc was incorrect.